# Can laravel's Authentication remember a user without password?

Tags: php, laravel

It's just a lunch order system for my company, and we can login in without password, but I try to

```
Auth::attempt(['name' => $name, 'email' => $email], true)
```

And it require password

Can I change this config?Or can it remember user in other way?

Comment: You will need to implement your own authentication provider, as laravels all assume you will pass them a hashed password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally you would want to implement your own authentication provider, as the defaults that come with Laravel all require a hashed password.

That said, as your requirements for authentication are so simple you could try to retrieve a User object for the credentials provided (email, name) and then pass that to the `Auth::login()` method to automatically log that user in.

```
// Get user record
$user = User::where('name', $name)->where('email', $email)->first();

// Probably want to make sure the user exists, otherwise return an error

// Log the user in (pass true as second parameter to remember then)
Auth::login($user, true);
```

Comment: What I want  is make the Application not only login the user but also make  remember the user by session or cookies.Not just login

Comment: Then just pass true as the second parameter to the login method :)

Answer (score 0):

When you register a new user, just hardcode the password, such as `secret`.

```
Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => 'secret', 'name' => $name], true);
```

Now you are just validating email and name.